# Find a folder with a partial name C#

Tags: c#, directory

I have a folder with a lot of projects, each folder is named in the same way:

```
8 characters + "space" + the name of the project

Example: 1234568 (Name of the project)
```

I am making a little GUI where I ask only the first 8 numbers of the project to open the corresponding folder.

So my question is....

**Is there a way to search for this folder WITHOUT reading all the folders aside?**

I was using this command `Process.Start(@"C:\Projects\12345678 Example");` but this one requires the exact folder name.

I am looking something like this `Process.Start(@"c:\Projects\12345678","*");`
but so far I have not been able to do it

Comment: You need to enumerate the existing folders until you find a match and the exact name - no magic short hand available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a search pattern in [`Directory.GetDirectories`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getdirectories?view=net-5.0#System_IO_Directory_GetDirectories_System_String_System_String_) method:

```
var dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(mainProjectsPath, "12345678*");
```

Notice the `*` in the second parameter, which specifies to look for each directory whose name start with the value you provide. You can of course build this pattern dynamically using string interpolation:

```
var projectNamePrefix = "1234567";
var dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(mainProjectsPath, $"{projectNamePrefix}*");
```

This will return an array of directory paths, if you are only interested in one directory, you can use `FirstOrDefault()` method to get it.